# Why won't my CSS Card Flip work?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to implement a flip card animation on my site but it won't work.  The transforms don't seem to be working.

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u2e6F/)

HTML:

```
<section class="cardContainer">
    <div id="card">
        <figure class="front">1</figure>
        <figure class="back">2</figure>
    </div>
</section>
```

JavaScript and CSS are on the fiddle.

Comment: Put your code here instead of just linking to it.

Comment: `toggleClass()` isn't animation... you have to use `.animate()` to achieve that result.

Comment: What do you expect `$` to do? You've not loaded any libraries.

Comment: @failed.down: He's using CSS3 transitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are lacking the use of style prefixes that a lot of browsers require for CSS3 rules.

Some common prefixes

```
-webkit-
-moz-
-o-
```

These prefixes have to be in-front of the following styles in your CSS file.

```
transform
transition
perspective
```

For example, taking one of the sections of you CSS, you will make the following change

```
#card.flipped {
  transform: rotateY( 180deg );
}

/* to */

#card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg );
}
```

Also make sure that you place the prefixes before the non-prefixed rule.

Comment: Dangit... I knew I was missing something small.  Should also add here that the following style also needed to have browser prefixes applied: